# JPA Collection of Embeddables

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa

I'm trying to persist a collection of embeddable/serializable objects as one of the fields in my entity.  I've seen the trick where you wrap the list in another serializable class and store the whole thing as a lob, but that feels like a hack.  As far as I can tell, the jpa way to do this is with an `@ElementCollection(targetClass=BlaBlaBla.class)` annotation on top of my list.  I have annotated my BlaBlaBla class to be Embeddable.

Unfortunately, Appengine gives me this exception:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Class "data.Contact" has collection field "properties" and this has no mapping in the table for the element class "data.EntityReference" 
org.datanucleus.jpa.NucleusJPAHelper.getJPAExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJPAHelper.java: 264) 
org.datanucleus.jpa.EntityTransactionImpl.commit(EntityTransactionImpl.java: 122) 
org.datanucleus.store.appengine.jpa.DatastoreEntityTransactionImpl.commit(DatastoreEntityTransactionImpl.java: 55)
```

Is the serializable class hack really necessary?  Any help would be hot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`@ElementCollection`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17410_01/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/ElementCollection.html) has been introduced in JPA 2.0 while [GAE/J currently only supports JPA 1.0](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/usingjpa.html). In other words, [`@ElementCollection`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17410_01/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/ElementCollection.html) is not available.

So either use the serialization hack (I don't like it) or map the association as a `OneToMany`.